# code for please wait the values are loading statement is appearing when we move from one intent to another intent

Tags: android

I am move from one intent to another intent,the another intent collects the data from  our own data base so,it takes so much time for appearing .In that idle time I want to display a animation like progerss dialogue etc.pleae give me the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet should give you an idea:

```
public static ProgressDialog getSpinningProgressDialog(Context ctx,
        int messageId) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(messageId));
    return dialog;
}
```

And `Activity` can manage dialogs itself, look for `onCreateDialog(..)`, `showDialog(..)`, `dismissDialog(..)`.